# Why Subject works some times?

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following code:

```js
public clearSearch$ = new Subject<boolean>();

this.clearSearch$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.searchResults$)).subscribe((groups: SearchGroup[]) =>
    groups.forEach((group) => {
        this.searchService.deleteResultGroup(group);
    }),
);
```

I call subject only once using click method:

```js
public clear() {
    this.clearSearch$.next();
}
```

Problem is when a new data comes to `this.searchResults$` the block `this.clearSearch$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.searchResults$)).subscribe()` works again. How to avoid it and call it only by click?

Comment: I suppose I need to unsubscribe from `clearSearch$` or take(1),, but I can not cause click should work any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (probably more, it's coding after all..).

Use a `take(1)` like you said. This won't unsubscribe from the `clearSearch$` just from the inner observable:

```js
this.clearSearch$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.searchResults$.pipe(take(1))
).subscribe((groups: SearchGroup[]) =>
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    this.searchService.deleteResultGroup(group);
  }),
);
```

This won't work if you place the `take(1)` on the outer observable:

```js
// this will only be triggered once. Don't use this
this.clearSearch$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.searchResults$),
  take(1)
).subscribe((groups: SearchGroup[]) =>
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    this.searchService.deleteResultGroup(group);
  }),
);
```

---

Or you can also use [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom):

```js
this.clearSearch$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.searchResults$)
).subscribe(([_, groups]) => {
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    this.searchService.deleteResultGroup(group);
  }),
});
```

Comment: This works `withLatestFrom`. Could you explan how does it work?

Comment: I think the name is pretty self explanatory :) nevertheless, it will only emit when both values have at least one emit. Once that happens, there will only be an emit to the subscribe when `clearSearch$` has an emit, however it will internally subscribe to `this.searchResults$`, and pass along the latest value to the subscribe

Comment: @user13314476 personally I like the `take(1)` approach more, because it actually unsubscribes from the inner observable, and that just feels better :D

Comment: @PoulKruijt Wouldn't `take(1)` approach work only once and all next clicks with `clear` won't do anything

Comment: @yurzui no, because like I mentioned, the `take(1)` only unsubscribes from `this.searchResults$`. Any next invocation of `clearSearch$` will resubscribe to the searchResults (once). The `take(1)` is placed on the inner observable, not on the outer observable. I'll update my answer so you can see the difference

Comment: Would definitely recommend the `withLatestFrom` option. There is no need to unsubscribe from it as it completes after emitting a value. That, and the code looks and feels much better to type.

Comment: @RobertDempsey mmm, can you explain with "there is no need to unsubscibe". Both solutions will still need an unsubscribe on destroy. Or is it so that if the observable within the `withLatestFrom` completes the entire observable completes? About code being cleaner, the function name itself is more descriptive, however the subscribe destructing makes it less appealing to me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z8glz7?devtoolsheight=60 console prints 1 once

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cd8jet?devtoolsheight=60 `withLatestFrom` doesn't break the chain of `clearSearch$.next();`

Comment: I mean you don't need to unsubscribe from the inner observable, the one returned by `withLatestFrom`

Comment: @yurzui that's because `searchResults` is a `Subject` there. You either need to use a `ReplaySubject` a `BehaviorSubject` or the `shareReplay` operator [see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qgfzpv?devtoolsheight=60). But it's good to know that `withLatestFrom` takes care of this. In that case I agree, the `withLatestFrom` is friendlier

Comment: @RobertDempsey if the inner observable emits a lot of times, it seems overhead to keep it subscribed to from within the `withLatestFrom`. Whereas `take(1)` does not have this "issue". But as mentioned above, `take(1)` does obviously need a replaying observable